# How can I organize table in MySQL from down to up?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which has gotten 100 rows and I would like to see these rows from down to up. How can I do that & what's the syntax in order to do this?

Comment: Order By <column_name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ORDER BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) of a SELECT query to order your resultset in a particular order.

```
SELECT field1, field2, FROM tablename ORDER BY field1 ASC, field2 DESC
```

ASC will order the resultset into ascending order, DESC into descending order. You can order by multiple fields as well.